# Как мобильные приложения с чатом понимают, когда получают новые сообщения?

Tags: android, ios, мобильные-приложения, push-уведомления, сниффер

Расскажу на примере: есть приложение Юла (ВКонтакте и проч) официальное. Как оно понимает при активном окне приложения, когда приходит новое сообщение?

При получении сообщения оно просто отправляет GET запрос именно на нужный чат и получает всю информацию оттуда.

Long Poll не вариант, потому что таймаут не наступает в логах снифера.
WebHook? не вариант ведь?
Push-уведомления? 
Как понять откуда приложение понимает когда нужно отправить GET запрос?

Comment: Устанавливаются двусторонние соединение, клиент, сервер, таким образом клиент с сервером и наоборот общается непрерывно.

Comment: По этой ссылки https://medium.com/@mayuroks/android-mvp-realtime-architecture-with-rxjava-and-socket-io-part-2-552f44fb943a  вы узнаете больше.

Comment: Нет там Get, зачем такой bounce делать, держиться сокет, емитит евент к примеру newMessage(chatId) и платформа рисует дальше. Без пушей не обойтись. LongPoll кстати иногда вариант.